# BootStrap col-md-4 aligning at right side for 4th object inside map function react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have 9 objects in an array, I want 3 items in one row, first row is fine, but second row first item going to right side

```
<div className='row'>
  { services?  services.map((d, i) => (
    <div key={i} className='col-md-4'>
       {d.image ? <img src={d.image} alt='' className="services-image " /> : <i className= 
       {d.icon}></i>}
       <h3>{d.name}</h3>
       <p>{d.text}</p>
    </div>
    ))
  : 'loading'}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a class in the **parent div**. And add styles.

```
<div className='service'>
  { services?  services.map((d, i) => (
    <div key={i}>
       {d.image ? <img src={d.image} alt='' className="services-image " /> : <i className= 
       {d.icon}></i>}
       <h3>{d.name}</h3>
       <p>{d.text}</p>
    </div>
    ))
  : 'loading'}
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.service{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 12px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```